# How to display the value of the a register in ti assembly for ti 83+/ti 84/ti 84+

Tags: assembly, calculator, texas-instruments, z80

All right, I shall cut down to the chase.
I am looking for a way (bcall() or some other method) to display the value that is currently held in the a register using the assembly for the ti 83 plus graphing calculator.

I do not care how complex the method as long as I am able to do it. thank you.

Comment: According to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TI_83_Plus_Assembly, the calculator has a Z80 CPU.  But any I/O is going to be calculator-specific, so I don't know the answer.  I only got as far as tagging this question with some relevant tags.

Comment: usually you need to convert the binary value to an ASCII string and display it ( according to http://tutorials.eeems.ca/ASMin28Days/lesson/toc.html the I83+ has a 'display string' function: bcall(_putS))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Tommylee2k, [here](http://tutorials.eeems.ca/ASMin28Days/lesson/day11.html#num) is a nice function:

> **`_DispHL`**: Displays the contents of the HL register right-justified in a field of five characters. For example, if HL = 125, output will be   '1' '2' '5'.

You don't need to reinvent the wheel.

```
LD H,0
LD L,A
B_CALL(_DispHL)
```

**Warning:** this subroutine destroys AF, DE and HL. So **`PUSH`** them before if you need them furthermore.